# How to rename part of a filename represented as string in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to rename/replace part of the string with a new name.

I have a string that represents a file including its path and file extension as shown below.

```
source_file = 'images/filename.jpg'
```

Below shows what I have tried so far. It works, however, is there a better way to produce the same outcome? I define 'better' by, shorter syntax and more efficient.

```
    import uuid

    source_file = 'images/filename.jpg'
    split = source_file.rsplit('/', 1)
    path, filename = split[0], split[1]

    ext = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1]

    # rebuild
    renamed = path + str(uuid.uuid4()) + ext
```

Comment: @Professor_Joykill , I had not considered that the string could use `os.path` function until posted. However, yes, OP could be a duplicate now this has been made clear by cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. I would like like to award points tho, as it helped me, please advise?

Comment: Feel free to mark an answer accepted regardless. :)

Answer (score 7):

You can take the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)  approach just as an alternative way to look at it and making use of a new awesome module.

So, you can take your path and create a `Path` object out of it:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('images/full_res/aeb2ffaf-2c4c-4c54-a356-fd0df7764222.jpg')

# get the name without extension
name_without_extension = p.stem
# extension part
ext = p.suffix

p.rename(Path(p.parent, renamed_file + ext))
```

More shortly:

```
p = Path('images/full_res/aeb2ffaf-2c4c-4c54-a356-fd0df7764222.jpg')
p.rename(Path(p.parent, 'new_uuid' + p.suffix))
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `os.path.split` to split your path into head and tail.
2. `os.path.splitext` splits the tail on extension, replace the tail with the new uuid
3. Call `os.path.join` to join head and new tail

---

```
In [1006]: head, tail = os.path.split('images/full_res/aeb2ffaf-2c4c-4c54-a356-fd0df7764222.jpg')

In [1008]: tail = str(uuid.uuid4()) + os.path.splitext(tail)[-1]

In [1010]: os.path.join(head, tail)
Out[1010]: 'images/full_res/a83e5a31-8d30-47d9-b073-d4439e0e4b2f.jpg'
```